I can't cancel out some terms in the Conformal invariance of 2D Laplace equation
I started with the equation
$$(\partial ^2_x + \partial _y ^2 ) f=0$$
Then I changed to $(r,w)$ co ordinates using a Conformal transform :
$$\partial _x= u \partial _r - v \partial w$$
$$\partial _y= v\partial _r + u \partial _w$$
where $u,v$ are functions of $x,y$.
Substituting in the first equation:
$$(u\partial _r - v\partial _w)^2 f+ (v\partial _r + u \partial _w)^2 f=0$$
So if the equation is invariant, I should be able to simplify this to $\partial ^2 r + \partial ^2 w=0$.
We have, using the product rule:
$$(u\partial _r - v\partial _w)^2f= u (\partial_r u ) \partial _r f + u^2 \partial ^2_r f -u(\partial _r v )\partial _w f -uv\partial _r \partial _w f- v(\partial _w u) \partial _r f-uv \partial _r \partial _w f+v (\partial _w v) \partial _w f+ v^2 \partial ^2 _ w f$$
Similarly,
$$(v\partial _r + u\partial _w)^2= v (\partial _r v)\partial_r f+ v^2\partial ^2 _r f + v(\partial _r u)\partial _w f+ uv \partial _r \partial _w f+ u(\partial _w v) \partial _r f+ uv \partial _w \partial _r f+ u(\partial _w u) \partial _w + u^2\partial ^2 _w f$$
Adding these two results, I am not able to get $\partial ^2 _w f +\partial ^2 _r f$ even after using commutativity of $\partial _w$ and $\partial _r$, as most terms don't cancel out. I am getting $(u^2+v^2) (\partial ^2 _r + \partial ^2_ w)+ \text {a bunch of extra terms}$.
How do I get rid of the extra terms?

you use the parts that dont cancel out to deduce the relationship between uv and rw

@user619894 what do you mean

Formally you get
$$\left(v \ \partial_r\ + \ u  \partial_w \right)^2 \  f(u,r,v,w) \ + \ 
\left( u \partial_r\ - \ v  \partial_w \right)^2 \ (f(u,r,v,w) \
  = \ (u^2\ + \ v^2) \  ({\partial_w}^2\ + \ {\partial_r}^2) \ f(u, r, v, w)$$

What happens to the rest of the terms I got?

Your notation does not indicate what differentiates what.  You must use brackets $$u \partial_r( u \partial_r f) = u^2 \partial_r (\partial_r f) = u^2 \partial_r^2 f$$ since all four new real variables are independent.

I have added the brackets

$u, v$ are functions of $(r,w)$. r,w are the co ordinates and u,v are the entries of the Jacobian matrix of the Conformal transform from (x,y) to (r,w)

By the basics $\partial_x =\frac{ \partial r}{\partial_x} \ \partial_r  + \frac{ \partial w}{\partial_x} \ \partial_w $  etc. These have to convert to their inverses using the inverse of tha Jacobian., such that u,v are functions of $r,w$. Partial derivatives are defined not by named direction , but in a general setting by the set of variables to be kept constant. Therefore I wrote 'formally' because there is a complex machinery of cancellations.
